# Customize Google Custom Search

Tags: google-custom-search

Does anyone know how to span the search result set over all of the links provided in google custom search . For Example, if I have provided sites like `site 1,site 2....site n` to search from ,then I want say top five results from all of these individual websites as JSON. Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a little late but might be able to help someone out .

This will return 2 results via the REST API for GCSE.

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=YOUR-KEY_HERE&cx=CX_HERE&fields=kind,items&filter=1&num=2&prettyPrint=true&q=querystring

its the num=2 part your looking for...